# Selenium - Java: Struggling to select a particular element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently creating a few scripts for a web application. I'm currently stuck on picking up a particular button. I've spend a few hours on it and still no luck. Any advice or guidance would be much appreciated. I've added the source code below as well as an image.

My current unsuccessful attempts:

```
chromeDriver.findElement(By.linkText("uploadfile")).click();
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[9]/input")).click();
chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//iput[@name='uploadfile']")).click
```

```
div style="display: block; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; opacity: 0; direction: ltr; z-index: 16777270; left: 835px; top: 313px; width: 232px; height: 46px; visibility: hidden;">
<input name="uploadfile" style="position: absolute; right: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 480px; font-family: sans-serif; cursor: pointer; height: 100%; z-index: 16777270;" type="file">
```

[image]

Comment: we need html code. Please share with us

Comment: What version of Selenium are you using? I assume your 3rd attempt was for "input" and not "iput". as @PotnuruRavi said, we need some more data, is the element you're selecting being added to the DOM as a result of a script? is it there from the start? is it visible? Selenium might have a problem with locating the element if it's not visible. In the worst case try to execute javascript from the driver with this command ((JavascriptExecutor) chromeDriver).executeScript(<command>)

Comment: After latest edit it's clear that the div containing the input is invisible (see style visibility: hidden on div). Selenium works with visible elements. You should either wait for that div to be visible (are you missing a step in your flow? are you not waiting using WebDriverWait for the change to happen to the DOM?) or force the div to be visible using the executeScript method from my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this path:-

```
  //input[@name='uploadfile' and @style='position: absolute; right: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 480px; font-family: sans-serif; cursor: pointer; height: 100%; z-index: 16777270;']
```